# invoking async rest service with jquery

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I am trying to invoke an asynchronous restful web service from jquery. The problem is that the HTTP client does not refresh when receiving the result, I have to refresh the browser manually.
This is the jquery code I am using:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({ 
             type: "GET",
             url: "http[...]",
             .done(function (data) {
             var res=data;
             $("#asy").html(res);
           })
           .fail(function () {
             alert("ERROR");
          });
        });
  </script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *Why do you want to refresh at all*!, you are using AJAX that means i do not want to refresh.
Or you mean to say `$("#asy").html(res);` is not working?

Comment: your code will only update #asy div,if refresh whole page why you are using ajax

Comment: Although "refresh" is a bad term to use, I read it to mean that the OP expects the targeted content to change (or "refresh" not the whole page/window.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the `success` function!

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: "http[...]",
    success: function (data) 
    {
        var res=data;
        $("#asy").html(res);
    },
    error: function ()
    {
        alert("ERROR");
    }
)};
```

Comment: `fail` is not a proper `ajax` option. You either pass a `success` and `error` in the `ajax` options, OR you chain `done` and `fail` off the returned deferred.

Comment: of course, you are absolutely right! I actually wanted to use error, just a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. Just wanted to make sure it hot cleared up. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code should work data receive is in json..

```
  $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "http[...]",
             data: "",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (msg) {
                 url += '&lat=' + msg[0].value;
                 url += '&lng=' + msg[1].value;
                 alert(url);
                 // more work here
             }
         });
```

Comment: This will work for a success condition, but has removed the OP's error handling. Also, it appears the OP would prefer to use the promise style of event handling by using `done` and `fail` off the returned deferred instead of passing `success` and `error` as options.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to make sure the OP learns the difference as it seems to be at the heart of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have `.done` in the wrong place. You're passing it as an ajax option instead of chaining it off the call to `.ajax` so that it is called off the returned deferred object. It needs to be chained in the same way that your `.fail` is chained.

```
$.ajax({
    //options
})
    .done(function () {
        // success logic
    })
    .fail(function () {
            // error logic
    });
```